# lief package error while installing MOBSF

Tags: python-3.x

Building wheel for lief (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-7w2iswl4
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/
Complete output (46 lines):
0.10.1
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 72, in run
subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

### Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 363, in 
setup(
File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 153, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 74, in run
raise RuntimeError("CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: " +
RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: lief

ERROR: Failed building wheel for lief
Running setup.py clean for lief
Failed to build lief
Installing collected packages: lief
Running setup.py install for lief ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hb45g1s1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/kali/.local/include/python3.8/lief
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/
Complete output (48 lines):
0.10.1
running install
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 72, in run
subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                        
                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                         
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                     
  File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 363, in <module>                                    
    setup(                                                                                                 
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup          
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup                                          
    dist.run_commands()                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands                                   
    self.run_command(cmd)                                                                                  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command                                    
    cmd_obj.run()                                                                                          
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run      
    return orig.install.run(self)                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run                                 
    self.run_command('build')                                                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command                                     
    self.distribution.run_command(command)                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command                                    
    cmd_obj.run()                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run                                   
    self.run_command(cmd_name)                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command                                     
    self.distribution.run_command(command)                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command                                    
    cmd_obj.run()                                                                                          
  File "/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py", line 74, in run                                          
    raise RuntimeError("CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: " +                     
RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: lief                              
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vgv9vwph/lief/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hb45g1s1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/kali/.local/include/python3.8/lief Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I think your question is not clear. We need some extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install CMake and it has to be in a path accessible by python.

If you are using homebrew,

> brew install cmake

Noticed you were using kali

> apt install cmake